# Transparencia en imagenes con ggimage en R

Tags: r, ggplot2

tengo esta gráfica a la que me gustaría darle un transparencia con el fin de ver el logo que queda detrás. Uso el package (ggimage) en un ggplot, la imagen viene de una url el código es el siguiente:

```
b_referenceteamadvanced.<- ggplot(b_referenceteamadvanced., aes(x=ORtg , y=DRtg, label=logos)) + 
   geom_image(aes(image = logos),alpha=0.1, size = 0.06, by = "width", asp = asp_ratio )+
   theme(aspect.ratio = 1/asp_ratio)+
   geom_hline(yintercept = mean(b_referenceteamadvanced.$DRtg), color = "#C9082A", linetype = "dashed") +
   geom_vline(xintercept = mean(b_referenceteamadvanced.$ORtg), color = "#C9082A", linetype = "dashed") +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#17408B", alpha=0.1)+
   theme_minimal()
```

[image: foto]

Comment: ¿Que logo? ¿transparencia a que elemento del gráfico?

Comment: Todos los logos, que dejen ver la parte de atrás o sea que no sean opacos que tengan algo de transparencia, gracias

Comment: Lo he intentado como se ve con Alpha, que funciona con los geom_point pero no funciona con los geom_image – Iván Villanueva Sabalete hace 3 horas   Eliminar

Comment: Es probable, por que la transparencia de una imagen depende de la propia imagen no de la función. Tampoco estoy seguro, pero deberías probar con alguna imagen  cuyo color de fondo sea transparente.

Comment: Patricio Moracho, he estado investigando y al parecer se logra con el paquete ggpmisc y la función geom_grob, pero todavía no entiendo muy bien cómo, porque al parecer hay que renderizar antes las imágenes. Sigo estudiándolo. Dejo aquí el enlace https://www.opensourcefootball.com/posts/2020-08-19-visualizing-the-runpass-efficiency-gap/ por si hay alguien mas habil que yo y le puede ayudar en algo